# Using multiple keystores in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore

I have multiple keystores: K1 stores common keys that are used by my application to when it connects to external ssl service. Also I have keystore K2 that contains certificates that are used by client application when it connects to my server application.
I use

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to K1>
```

and

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="200"
                   enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                   acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
                   keystoreFile="<K2>" keystorePass="..." keystoreType="JKS"
                   keyAlias="tomcat"/>
```

in my tomcat config. When I added 1st line (-D) to work with another https service Tomcat starts to fails and it's https connector is not running:

Apr 28, 2014 9:05:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getStore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path /data/iris/apps/iris-us-dev/security/riskblotter-keystore due to Keystore was tampered with, or password w
as incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

```
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 28, 2014 9:05:56 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 28, 2014 9:05:56 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/23  config=null
Apr 28, 2014 9:05:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getStore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path <PATH TO K1> due to Keystore was tampered with, or password w
as incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:771)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
```

Looks like it tries to use K1 as a keystore for HTTPS connector, while K2 should be used. Is it possible to have multiple keystores in this case?

Comment: Why not use the specific keystores at app level intead of at app container level? In my opinnion this is not a good practice, the app container should be abstract to the applications. Anyway, I think the JVM command line property prevails over the tomcat config.

Comment: @vzamanillo, could you please explain about app/container level? I have a 3rd party client jar that uses ssl connection. And it fails to establish it and hangs if I don't specify -D parameter..

Comment: @vzmanillo Impossible. The connector is server-wide, and so therefore is its keystore. By the time the application is called, SSL handshaking is already complete. You can use a per-application truststore, but why? A trusted certificate is a trusted certificate. Nothing application-specific about it.

Comment: I am not talking about the server certificates keystore, the K2 has sense, but K1 could be used at application level without any problems because is used to connect to external services. If you build a new application in the future to connect to another external services, what do you do?

Comment: @vzamanillo, what do you mean by using at application level, is it a passing path to certificate to the library using it's settings? As I mentioned, it is 3rd party jar and they suggest to use -D or importing it into JRE keystore.

Comment: @dbf, at application level means that you use the keystores per app, opening, reading and using it by code instead of setting a keystore as default trustore to the JVM. If you are using a 3rd party library, obviously, is not possible :(, anyway the JVM property overrides the tomcat config, so probably your solution is a single keystore with all needed certs.

Comment: @ user207421 "A trusted certificate is a trusted certificate. Nothing application-specific about it." - Interesting. So if you deploy Facebook and Twitter on the same WAS then all Facebook users become trusted by Twitter.